# Add constraint to table with check in Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, constraints

I would like to `ALTER` my existing table by adding `CONSTRAINT` to specific column to respect some regex.

I try to normalize phone prefix number by executing:

```
ALTER TABLE users
    ADD CONSTRAINT users_prefix_constraint 
        CHECK (users.phone_prefix ~ '^\+\d{1,3}$');
```

And it's working correctly.

But I would like to use it more generic and define `DOMAIN` which holds regex pattern, to use the same pattern in different places (i.e. in triggers). That's why I imagine to do something like:

```
CREATE DOMAIN ph_prefix AS TEXT CHECK (VALUE ~'^\+\d{1,3}$');

ADD CONSTRAINT users_prefix_constraint CHECK (users.phone_prefix :: ph_prefix);
```

Problem here is, that `CHECK` part expects some function returning `boolean`, and casting doesn't.

1. Is there a way to do it?
2. Is that a good way to define constraint? Maybe it's not preferred way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing the point of domains.

You would not add a domain as a constraint, but you would use it as the data type for a column:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER phone_prefix TYPE ph_prefix;
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed the clearest solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reason to define a domain but *not* use it as a data type of `users.phone_prefix` column then create this simple function

```sql
create or replace function ph_prefix_valid(s text) returns boolean as
$$
begin
 perform s::ph_prefix;
 return true;
exception when others then
 return false;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and then

```sql
ADD CONSTRAINT users_prefix_constraint CHECK (ph_prefix_valid(users.phone_prefix));
```